# Can I hook into user registration *before* a user is created?

Tags: user-registration, limit

I want to limit registration based on the domain associated with their email address. I was looking at the `user_register` action hook, but it fires *after* the user is already inserted, which, although it could be hacked into working, is less than ideal. I want to preempt rather than retroactively remove invalid users.

I've looked through the source in `wp-includes/user.php`, but nothing in there looks to be helpful. I did notice the `pre_user_email` filter, but that doesn't seem to offer any options for doing anything useful since I can't see a way to do anything with that.

Comment: Related: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/95300, https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/167554

Comment: Excellent, comprehensive article: https://usersinsights.com/wordpress-user-registration-hooks-visualized/

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You're looking in the wrong place.

When a user first attempts to register, their username and email is processed and sanitized inside the `register_new_user()` function in `wp-login.php`.  This is where you want to do your filtering.

Before the user is created, WordPress will pass the sanitized user login, email address, and an array or errors through the 'register_post' action.  If there are any errors after that, then the user is not added and they will see the errors in the UI.

So the following *untested* function might help:

```
function prevent_email_domain( $user_login, $user_email, $errors ) {
    if ( strpos( $user_email, '@baddomain.com' ) != -1 ) {
        $errors->add( 'bad_email_domain', '<strong>ERROR</strong>: This email domain is not allowed.' );
    }
}
add_action( 'register_post', 'prevent_email_domain', 10, 3 );
```

Comment: What is the difference between "registration_errors" filter and "register_post" action?

Comment: The `register_post` action lets you trigger other functionality before the user is created. The `registration_errors` filter lets you inject an "error" into the functionality and short-circuit the registration action entirely.

Answer (score 1):

This depends if you are building your own custom registration form where you implement the actual user registration or if you are using the registration form provided by WordPress.

If you are using the former, there aren't any since you'll have access to the `POST` data and be the one responsible for calling `wp_insert_user()` or `wp_create_user()` and making sure all the required info is correct i.e. username, email..

For the latter case, hook into `register_post` action. This is found in `wp-login.php` inside `register_new_user()` function.

```
/**
 * Code snippet...
 */
 } elseif ( email_exists( $user_email ) ) {
    $errors->add( 'email_exists', __( '<strong>ERROR</strong>: This email is already registered, please choose another one.' ) );
}

do_action( 'register_post', $sanitized_user_login, $user_email, $errors );

$errors = apply_filters( 'registration_errors', $errors, $sanitized_user_login, $user_email );

/** rest of the code after... **/
```