# How to override WordPress registration and insert an auto-generated username?

Tags: functions, hooks, user-registration, username

I need to auto-generate usernames upon WordPress registration. I have a custom registration form set up and would like to create the username in functions.php.

Can someone tell me why this isn't working? It seems like it should work after reading the [WordPress Codex on customized registration forms](http://codex.wordpress.org/Customizing_the_Registration_Form)?

```
function register_hook ( $user_id ) {
  update_user_meta( $user_id, 'signup_username', 'the-auto-generated-name' );
  // also tried this:
  // update_user_meta( $user_id, 'user_login', 'the-auto-generated-name' );
}
add_action( 'user_register', 'register_hook' );
```

Comment: do you mean the user login name? that's not stored in user meta, it's a column in the users table.

Comment: yes, that's what i mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One alternative is to modify the `$_POST['user_login']` input value when submitting new registration form, that is before WP process the registration form. A good hook to achieve this is `login_form_register` that fires before processing and rendering registration form. `login_init` also works but need more work to make sure we are on `register` action.

```
add_action('login_form_register', 'custom_user_login');
function custom_user_login() {

    // make sure regisration form is submitted
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] != 'POST')
        return;

    // base of user_login, change it according to ur needs
    $ulogin = 'random-user';

    // make user_login unique so WP will not return error
    $check = username_exists($ulogin);
    if (!empty($check)) {
        $suffix = 2;
        while (!empty($check)) {
            $alt_ulogin = $ulogin . '-' . $suffix;
            $check = username_exists($alt_ulogin);
            $suffix++;
        }
        $ulogin = $alt_ulogin;
    }

    $_POST['user_login'] = $ulogin;
}
```

Comment: Hi Ahmad, thanks for your response. I tried out your code and removed the "signup_username" field from my registration form, but WP keeps returning the registration form and not completing because the 'signup_username' is empty. I also tried updating the second to last line in your code from 'user_login' to 'signup_username', but it didn't make a difference. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you using default `wp-login.php?action=register` or a custom URL?

Comment: A custom url -- /register

Comment: The concept is the same, but you might need to update the code above to overwrite whatever `$_POST` value passed to `register_new_user()` or `wp_insert_user()` as the user login name. Also the hooks mentioned above only works on `wp-login.php`, so you will need to change it to a hook that fires before processing the form, `init` or `after_setup_theme` might work depending on at what point the form is processed.

Answer (score 1):

You can alter user login via the `pre_user_login` filter. Note that this runs when the user is created *or updated*.

```
function wpd_custom_user_login( $user_login ) {
    $user_login = 'the-auto-generated-name';
    return $user_login;
}
add_filter( 'pre_user_login' , 'wpd_custom_user_login' );
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! I just need to auto generate the username one time -- right after they successfully complete the registration form. How can it be made to only run then? Is the user_register hook correct?

Comment: You can hook the [`register_post`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.0/src/wp-includes/user.php#L2143) action to add your filter right before new users are registered.